# Hiding elements with JS

Tags: javascript, css

**UPDATE:**

I changed my script to this and it works. Way simpler and it works.

```
            function myFunction(valor) {            
                var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
                var i;
                for (i = 1; i < elementos.length+1; i++) {
                        document.getElementById("age"+i).style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                document.getElementById("age"+valor).style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```

---

I have this script:

```
function myFunction(valor) {
    alert("Has seleccionado " + valor);
    var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
    //alert ("Tienes " + elementos.length + " elementos.");
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < elementos.length + 1; i++) {
        var sty = document.getElementById("age" + i);
        //alert("age"+i);
        if (getComputedStyle(sty).getPropertyValue("visibility") == "hidden") {
            document.getElementById("age" + valor).style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("age" + i).style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

That I control with a slider control. What I'm doing is hiding or showing some divs with depending of what I choose from the slider.

This is how I paint my data before trying to hide or shsow elements with the slider:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://xxxxx/xxxxx.json', function(data) {
        var output = "<ul class='lista'><div class='outer'>";
        for (var i in data.lbclassic) {
            output += "<div style='visibility:hidden;' class='inner'id=" + "age" + data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks + ">" + "<p>" + data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].cumul + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].perhh + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].perhd + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggweightinweek + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggmasscumul1 + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggmassinweek + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggmasscumul + "</p></div>";
        }
        output += "</div></ul>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
    });
});
```

This works great until one point - once I get to the last element (90 in this case), it won't show up.

Comment: Could it be an issue with how the elements are being indexed? In the top code you're looking for elements in the range 1 < x < length + 1, but in the bottom you're setting the id as 'data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks' - you may want to check the numbers correspond to each other

Comment: I think you just need to start your loop from i=0 ,and if you have the ids like age1,age2...etc (so they start from 1) , then you just add 1, like this : `var sty = document.getElementById("age" + (i+1));`

Comment: Thanks guys, I finally thought of something else, which IMO is simpler, I updated the thread.

Comment: You keep declaring new variables `var sty = document.getElementById("age" + i);`. It's better to declare it outside your loop only once and then keep using it `sty = document.getElementById("age" + i);`

Comment: Wanted to keep declaring it because I wanted to loop through each ID and check its style. However now I fixed the script, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function myFunction(valor) {            
        var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < elementos.length+1; i++) {
                document.getElementById("age"+i).style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        document.getElementById("age"+valor).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it more easy to use the css "display:none;" feature for hidding your element.

```
.yourclass{
     display:none;
}
```

just edit the class with js

[Link to CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: Yes, I know about that CSS rule but it'd be the same case, my problem was with the looping. Thank you!